# I added the arrow in the select with Chosen plugin But it does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less, jquery-chosen

I use the Chosen plugin, I have added multiple arrows. I set the height to select and it will automatically show scrollbars if multiple items are selected.

Now, when the scroll bar is displayed, if I scroll the scroll bar, the arrow disappears.

I want when the scroll bar is displayed. If the scroll bar scrolls down, the arrow will keep displaying to the right of the input.

I tried many ways but it does not work, because the image is using the `position: absolute` attribute

This is my code:

```
.chosen-container-multi.chosen-container ul.chosen-choices::after{

        background: url(https://image.ibb.co/cdSC2e/Select_Arrow.png) center center no-repeat !important;
        width: 33px;
        height: 50px;
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        /*position: fixed; */
        right: 9px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hv0d46b8/19/

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added arrow in pseudo element with respective to UL but should be called with respective to UL's parent div

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q1ydnc8/)

```
.chosen-container-multi.chosen-container::after{

        background: url(https://image.ibb.co/cdSC2e/Select_Arrow.png) center center no-repeat !important;
        width: 33px;
        height: 100%;
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        /*position: fixed; */
        right: 14px;
        top: 0px;

}
```

Comment: I tried your way, and it worked fine, but there is one small thing, when the scrollbar is displayed, I want the arrow to be pushed to the left a little bit, meaning it's always padding-right about 14px The
Is that possible?